# Send Intent to Google Drive App to view File

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have Google Drive installed on my device.

My App uses the Google Drive API to upload video files.

I would like to send an Intent to Google Drive itself, so that it can play the video file for me.

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like getWebContentLink() will actually do this. I thought it would only access the web browser, but Drive appears in the list and works exactly how I needed it to.